# Is "Raining Cats and dogs" still used nowadays?

Tags: idioms

Is it old-fashioned to say "It's raining cats and dogs"? 
If yes, what is the substitution idiom for expressing heavy rain?

Comment: It still used today to indicate *(extremely) heavy* rain or rainfall. It is not considered old-fashioned. It is an idiomatic expression.

Comment: As a side note, when it is raining that hard be careful not to step in a poodle.

Comment: How about "it's raining frogs and fishes"

Comment: I still use it - but it's not as bad as hailing taxis.

Comment: It's rainy AF. No one's heard this before?

Comment: Where & how did the phrase originate? Why cats & dogs?

Comment: Depends on who you ask, but as a 35-year-old native English speaker from the US, I can tell you with certainty that it *is* considered outdated to the point of being amusing to many people. It's extremely likely this depends on where you're from, and being an idiom does not preclude a phrase from being perceived as old-fashioned. "It's pouring" is much more current.

Comment: @AlexS There are many stories about its origin; e.g. that people kept their cats and dogs out in the yard and they remained outside at all times, except when the weather was so bad that they came seeking shelter inside.

Comment: There is another saying. It goes as "It is raining in sheets."

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> It's raining cats and dogs

is used to describe very heavy rain and is still in use these days.

[image: here]

Alternative phrasing might be

> It's pouring
>   It's bucketing
>   It's a deluge
>   It's pissing down *(BrE)*
>   It's really coming down *(can be used for any precipitation )*

[image: here]

Comment: One more as I remember - it's ***teeming*** :)

Comment: I've personally (AmE) never heard "It's bucketing," but I have heard "It's raining buckets."

Comment: It's chucking it down! It's tipping it down out there!

Comment: I like "There certainly is plenty of weather today"

Comment: +1 for the effort in finding these images, oh, and also for the excellent answer.

Comment: It's in use - but I've only heard it said in the last decade from my grandmother. The most common idiom I've heard is "it's [insert colloquialism for urination]ing it down"

Comment: In Australia (and I believe UK too), we say "It's pissing down", or if extremely heavy "It is absolutely pissing down"

Comment: My personal favourite is 'coming down like stair-rods' but I don't think I've ever heard anyone use it in RL - maybe in period fiction.

Comment: One would assume the RP version would be _the fog has cleared_.

Comment: BTW, _pissing down_ is considered a little coarse. You would use it in a business setting, but not when addressing a judge for example.

Comment: @alex_d I can attest “It's bucketing” from Western Canada. It seems to be an adaptation of the (also used) phrase “It's raining buckets”.

Comment: If *it's pissing it down* isn't coarse enough, try [*it's shitting it down*](https://twitter.com/search?q=%22shitting+it+down%22), which can be further emphasised with *it's absolutely shitting it down* or *it's fucking shitting it down*. Not for polite conversation.

Comment: Where & how did the phrase originate? Why cats & dogs?

Comment: @AlexS - [No one knows](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=rain&allowed_in_frame=0). From etymonline.com: _Phrase 'to rain cats and dogs' is attested from 1738 (variation 'rain dogs and polecats' is from 1650s), of unknown origin, despite intense speculation._

Comment: Supposedly, in olden times animals would hide in the attic spaces of thatched houses, and when it rained heavily the water would seep through the roof making the attic space slippery which then would cause the cats or dogs to fall. This has always been my understanding of the idiom [here](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-rai1.htm)

Answer (score 18):

Perhaps nowadays the saying is less popular among young native speakers, it does sound a bit of a cliché. According to [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=raining%20cats%20and%20dogs&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Craining%20cats%20and%20dogs%3B%2Cc0), the **British English** corpus shows its popularity has declined since its peak in the 1940s.

[image]

Whereas according to Google Ngrams, it seems that **American English** speakers are *loving* it, the chart shows a sharp increase in usage since the 1970s.

[image]

[Ngram link](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=raining%20cats%20and%20dogs&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Craining%20cats%20and%20dogs%3B%2Cc0)

To add to the many colloquial sayings mentioned already by @Peter and @Jocie,  the very common, but perhaps for some speakers offensive, phrase:

> [**It's pissing down**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/piss-down)

and the innocuous-sounding

> **It's pelting down**

Comment: I've always heard "pelting down" solely for hail. For me, "pelting" implies being *painfully* hit with something, or hit in a way that might damage.

Comment: It's probably a regional thing, in BrEng it is used for very heavy rain.

Comment: I believe the word "cliché" is now cliché, too...

Comment: A personal fav of mine is: "I think a cloud crash landed"

Comment: Just a note, in case visitors are wondering,  Peter added "it's pissing down"  in his answer *after* I had posted this suggestion.

Answer (score 8):

It entirely depends on where you are in the world, right down to the city. I'm from Lincolnshire in England and I have **never** heard anyone say "it's raining cats and dogs" without them being silly or making a joke.

Locally we'd say "it's chucking it down"

Comment: Does use of an idiom become less valid if it was intended to be humorous?

Comment: Or (possibly Yorkshire dialect rather than pure Lincolnshire) "It's siling [with rain]". (Pronounced with a long "i" vowel, as in "eye"). From the Norse  "sila", to pour something through a strainer, apparently.

Comment: +1 for the very local nature of these things - in NYC, "it's raining cats and dogs" is maybe a little old-fashioned, but that's all; "it's chucking it down" would not be understood at all.

Comment: @Gusdor Perhaps "joke" isn't the right word, more taking the mick out of the mid-20th century. Normally (again, in my experience) it would be voiced in a particular way (perhaps an older, Yorkshire/farmer-like accent, it's hard to describe in written form). To answer OPs question, "Is it old-fashioned", for my locale? Absolutely.

Comment: @Jocie i spend a significant amount of time outdoors in unpleasant weather and uttering _"its cats and dogs out there"_ or _"its blowing dogs off chains"_ or _"its blowing crabs out the sand"_ is more common than you'd think.

Comment: @Gusdor I've been around a good part of the U.S., and live near Washington, D.C., and I've *never* heard those last two - but great imagery, I must say!  Those have to be U.K. English expressions, if I had to guess.

Comment: @alephzero I grew up in West Yorkshire and my parents still live there. Never heard "siling" in my life.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, "cats and dogs" is still in use and almost all Americans will understand.  There is also the airplane pilot's description of truly bad weather when driving a car:  "It's IFR weather out there" (Instrument Flight Rules), meaning (jokingly) you can't see a dang thing through the windshield and you must use your car's oil pressure gauge to steer by.